# Dictionary python, don't write existing word

Tags: python, dictionary

I want that if a word already exit in Dico.txt it doesn't write it again.

```
e = input("Mots: ")
f = e.split(" ")

with open("Dico.txt", "a") as f2:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            f2.write(word + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list for this:

```
e = input("Mots: ")
f = e.split(" ")
u = []

with open("Dico.txt", "a") as f2:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if not word in u:
              f2.write(word + '\n')
              u.append(word)
            else:
              continue
```

Comment: or a set.. just add each word to a set. and convert at end too list

Comment: Thanks but u.append(word) doesn't work. error :
'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = open('Dico.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('new.txt', 'w')
w = input('The word? ')
for line in f:
  for word in line.split():
    l = line.replace(w, "")
  f2.write(l.strip(" "))
```